# Add a view in a body of the tab

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have a tab but could not figure out how to add a view inside the body of a specific tab. For instance I want a list in tab "first", how can I add this component here? Thankyou in advance.

```
import Tabs from 'react-native-tabs';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {page:'second'};
  }
  render() {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Tabs selected={this.state.page} style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
              selectedStyle={{color:'red'}} onSelect={el=>this.setState({page:el.props.name})}>
            <Text name="first">First</Text>
            <Text name="second" selectedIconStyle={{borderTopWidth:2,borderTopColor:'red'}}>Second</Text>
            <Text name="third">Third</Text>
            <Text name="fourth" selectedStyle={{color:'green'}}>Fourth</Text>
            <Text name="fifth">Fifth</Text>
        </Tabs>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              Welcome to React Native
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              Selected page: {this.state.page}
          </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => Example);
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the "First", "Second"... `<Text>` tags with a `<View>`?

Comment: How to do that? If Text with "welcome to react native" is replaced with view (or any other component), it'll be visible to all the tabs body. I'm stuck at - How can I set any view / component for a particular tab?

Answer (score 0):

The `react-native-tabs` package takes each child of the `<Tabs>` tag and wraps it into a separate component that will only be shown when the tab is selected. So what you have to do is the following:

```
render() {
  var self = this;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Tabs selected={this.state.page} style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
            selectedStyle={{color:'red'}} onSelect={el=>this.setState({page:el.props.name})}>
          <View name="view">
              <Text>Text Wrapped inside a view</Text>
          </View>
          <View name="custom component" selectedIconStyle={{borderTopWidth:2,borderTopColor:'red'}}>
              <MyCustomComponent/>
          </View>
          <Text name="third">Third</Text>
          <Text name="fourth" selectedStyle={{color:'green'}}>Fourth</Text>
          <Text name="fifth">Fifth</Text>
      </Tabs>
    </View>
);
```

Everything rendered outside the `<Tabs>` tag will appear no matter which tab is selected.